# Xamarin side menu tap issue

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I developed an app using Xamarin forms that has side menu [see this url](https://github.com/ScienceSoft-Inc/ScnSideMenu).
But I couldn't use this in my current project, so I made my custom component for side menu.

How to implementing feature that hide menu when I tap range out of side menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give you any help without seeing your code, but generally I tackle this issue by adding a `ContentView` that covers the screen when ever your menu opens. The menu would be displayed on top of the `ContentView`. Then you add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `ContentView` which closes the menu when clicked.

You could add some color to the `ContentView` but make it opaque so it is see-through, something like this color: `#74787878`

```
ContentView backgroundView = new ContentView {
    BackgroundColor   = Color.FromHex("#74787878"),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions   = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Content           = //Your menu
}

backgroundView.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer {
    Command = new Command(() => {
        //Remove the background and hide the menu
    })
});
```